# how to fix a method that works only with even indexes?

Tags: java

i wrote this method that checks whether there's a digit that is contained inside a next array's index's number , if there is at least 1 digit that is a part of the next number , it will go in a counter and if the counter's value is more than 0 it will go inside  a variable "check" that will be equal true.
 it's enough to have 1 index that is false to make the whole array false. they all have to be true;
 for example an array that is correct according to the method i built: int [] arr = {12,527,71,114,49,1902};

thats for the method explaintion. now for my problem.
**the method works only with even numbers** and i dont know what could go work. thanks to all the helpers!

```
public static boolean checkSpecialArray(int[] arr)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int x = 0;
        boolean check = true;
        int counter = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)// array's length
        {String Dig = Integer.toString(arr[i++]);//next array's number
        String num = Integer.toString(arr[i]);//first array's number
            for (j = 0; j < num.length(); j++)// check first array's index number
                for (x = 0; x < Dig.length(); x++)// check 2nd array's index number
                    if (Integer.parseInt("" + num.charAt(j)) == Integer.parseInt("" + Dig.charAt(x)))//checks a digit to another digit
                        counter++;
                    
            if(counter>0)
            check = true;
                else if(counter==0)
                 return false;
            
            counter=0;  
        }
        if(check)
            return true;
        
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What does it do with odd numbers?

Comment: Side note:  instead of `Integer.parseInt("" + num.charAt(j)) == Integer.parseInt("" + Dig.charAt(x))` doing `num.charAt(j) == Dig.charAt(x))` should be sufficient since you want to check characters/digits and not values.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have to guess here but I assume this is the source of your problem:

```
 for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // array's length 
   String Dig = Integer.toString(arr[i++]);//next array's number
```

Here you are incrementing `i` inside the loop as well so it skips numbers. You'd probably want to do `Integer.toString(arr[i + 1])` instead.

Note that `i++` basically is the same as `i += 1` or `i = i + 1`, so having that in your loop's "next" operation (3rd part of the for-construct) as well as in the body basically makes the loop body start with indices 0, 2, 4, etc. which seems to only use even indices.

Also, having `String num = Integer.toString(arr[i]);` at the second line basically uses the "next" number and not the first.

Finally `i < arr.length;` would cause problems for arrays of odd length because in the body you'd try to access a non-existing index at the end (due to that `i++` but even a `i + 1` would cause this).

Why do you need that (as per the question in your comment)?

Since you are trying to compare numbers at indices `i` and `i + 1` you need to make sure that `i` doesn't "leave" the array, i.e. the maximum allowable index would be `array.length - 2`. This is because indices are zero-based so the last allowable index for an array would be `array.length - 1` (e.g. 4 in an array of length 5).

Now let's consider the options for the loop condition:

- `i<arr.length` - this would allow `i` to refer to the last index in the array and thus `arr[i + 1]` would be out of bounds, hence the exception you got
- `i<=arr.length` - this would allow `i` to get even more out of bounds and `arr[i]` would fail already
- `i<arr.length-1` - this would restrict `i` to only refer indices up to the second-to-last (e.g. index 3 in an array of length 5) and hence `arr[i + 1]` would still be within bounds and refer to the last element.

So you'd want to have the loop look like this:

```
//from first to second-to-last index
for (i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
  String num = Integer.toString(arr[i]);//first array's number

  //also note the lowercase variable name which is more according to the Java code conventions
  String dig = Integer.toString(arr[i+1]);//next array's number
```

Alternatively you could use an enhanced for loop, e.g. like this:

```
 String prev = null;

 for( Integer num : arr ) {
   //or use Math.abs(num) to also be able to handle negative integers easily
   String next = Integer.toString(num);

   //only if there was a previous number
   if( prev != null ) {
     //compare digits/characters here
   } 

   //keep reference to the "current" number in string form to act as previous in the next iteration
   prev = next;
 }
```

Comment: isnt it the same thing? i++ = i + 1?
and it will not work the way you suggested ( i + 1 )

Comment: @avihu24 no, `i++` is basically the same as `i = i + 1`.

Comment: now it will not work at all , Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
 at test_2.checkSpecialArray(test_2.java:141)
 at home.main(home.java:14)

Comment: @avihu24 yes, that was to be expected since you have another error as well. Look at the updated answer, I've addressed that already.

Comment: about the lower case , i'm using numbers only
should i switch between the dig , and num lines ?

Comment: thomas , can you explain please why do i need to minus the array length by 1? (arr.length-1) why cant i write i<=arr.length instead?

Comment: @avihu24 I'll add that to the answer and also added an alternative loop implementation.